# Convay's Life Python

Tags: python, python-3.x, инспекция-кода, numpy

Начал знакомиться с питоном - решил реализовать простейшую версию игры "Жизнь" Конвея, но на данном этапе не могу понять, почему она работает не верно - некоторые клетки оживают, хотя соседей у них менее или более 3, а некоторые убивает, хотя соседей 2-е или трое.
Код залил на гитхаб, потому что тут его было бы многовато: [код](https://github.com/Lesaje/wall-nut/blob/Convay0.1/New%20Conveys.py).

Лично я грешу на 2 проблемы: первое это правильно ли указаны координаты(в самом начале при чтении построчно, x и y должны соответствовать осям абсцисс и ординат соответственно) а второе это проблемы с записью и чтением в вспомогательный список(new_universe), но где именно ошибка - я не знаю

Буду благодарен за любую помощь!

Comment: Во-первых, Ваша ссылка ведёт на [StackOverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/). А во-вторых, вопрос слишком общий. Мне кажется, что копаться в большом количестве кода на стороннем ресурсе не всем захочется.

Comment: Ваши длиннейшие проверки на крайние и угловые поля можно убрать, если считать соседей внутри try..except.

Comment: Не могли бы уточнить, что такое try..except и как его использовать?

Comment: Да вообще код очень не оптимален, как-то по-другому надо соседей считать.

Comment: Мог бы, конечно, но не буду. Не люблю копипастить учебники. Подскажу, что тут пригодится IndexError.

Comment: @CrazyElf Да, тоже об этом думал - одна проверка для списка размером 1000х1000 занимает около 32 секунд на моём железе - но не придумал пока, как оптимизировать. Буду рад вашим мыслям)

Comment: @OlehChaika Ну я бы попробовал что-то типа наложения маски, чтобы не по точкам, а как-то сразу куском всё считать. Дальше не могу уже помочь, работы много и всё такое. Наверняка эта тема много раз уже разбиралась в интернетах, надо гуглить.

Comment: Я бы вообще не хранил такую  большую матрицу. Все равно там почти все клетки пустые. Хранить надо только  map с  координатами  живых для быстрого поиска.

Answer (score 3):

Вы пишете новые данные в ту же самую матрицу, на основе которой вычисляете "новую вселенную", у вас `universe` и `new_universe` указывают на одну и ту же область памяти. Поэтому ваши вычисления базируются на данных, уже частично изменённых на текущей итерации и из-за этого заведомо не являются корректными.

Вам нужно явным образом копировать вашу матрицу вселенной в новый объект:

```
while i < k:
    universe = new_universe.copy()
```

Comment: Хехе, даже не смотря в код, я был уверен, что проблема именно в этом. Самая частая проблема у тех, кто "жизнь" пишет. Тут ещё хоть два поля, а то бывает вообще в то же самое пишут.

Comment: Если я не ошибаюсь, numpy.zeros заполняет список нулями, не могу понять, в чем смысл этого. Что пишу в один и тот же список я понял

Comment: У нас после заполнения нулями новой вселенной выйдет полностью мертвый массив, в котором мы затем расставим некоторые точки, причем только там, где в "старой" вселенной будут 3 соседа-единицы, при этом мы потеряем те живые клетки, которые не меняются(при наличии 2 соседей - единиц), то есть получим не тот список, что хотели(ну или я чего-то не понимаю)

Comment: @Эникейщик Да я вообще периодически этот косяк тут встречаю в коде, люди почему-то думают, что простое присваивание автоматически новую копию создаёт.

Comment: @OlehChaika Ну я в код не вдавался особо. Наверное, вам и правда нужна просто копия. Уберу лишнее тогда, если вы на основе старой вселенной должны обязательно делать, не с нуля всё заполняете, а только меняете то, что поменялось.